# Creating second ASP.NET MVC authentication cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

I am working in a ASP.NET MVC 5 application where I need two levels of security. 
Users log in the system and after that, they have the option to "log in" in a second subsystem (let's think a company branch) selecting one company branch from a list of company branches. This scenario is similar to have a GitHub account with some repositories. First, you log in GitHub and then you select the repository to work on it.
I don't want to pass the branch id/name as an url parameter, I want to create a cookie to store branch basic data such as id and name.
I am creating a cookie (using HttpCookie) with company branch data. My question is what is the best way to create (and encrypt) this second cookie to identify the selected company branch?

Comment: On GitHub, you don't "log on" to the repository. You just choose it, and then you're taken to the proper URL for viewing the page. Why don't you just configure your routing that way? I'd avoid cookies for this. That makes it difficult to share links to a consistent page.

Comment: I made a reference to GitHub as example. I don't want to query my database for each request to get Company Branch Name and other basic Company Branch data (from route parameters such as company branch id/name). Company Branch data is used to implement authorization so I prefer to have some company branch data in "cache" (so far in a cookie) that to query my database for get it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A user could easily manipulate the cookie. Your server will have to determine authorization for the request anyways. A small auth check database query should be pretty easy and fast. And if it's not, then you can cache the result in server memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use roles to manage access to the different branches. The dropdown list shouldn't even show the branch if the user doesn't have access to it in the first place, and the controller action for the branch page should be decorated with an `[Authorize]` attribute. Then it's fine if you leave the branch ID or whatever in the URL. An unauthorized user wouldn't be able to view it if they changed it anyway. http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/security/16-adding-security-and-membership

Comment: I already have a security mechanism with membership and role provider. I am using Owin. The problem is not other one. Authorization has been implemented in all action and controller. I am looking for a good way to keep extra data such as the company branch that user select. I don't want to query my database in each request to get Company Branch Name and other basic Company Branch data.

Comment: Use ASP.NET session for those types of values then.